# Not able to read data from AWS S3(orc) through Intellij local(spark/Scala)

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, intellij-idea, amazon-s3

we are reading the date/table from AWS(hive) through Spark/scala using Intellij(witch is on local machine). we can able to see the schema of table. but not able to read data.

please find below flow to get better understanding

Intellij(spark/scala)------> hive:9083(remote)------> s3(orc)

Note: Here Intellij is present on local and hive and S3 present on AWS

Please find below code for the same:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
//import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext


object hiveconnect {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("SparkHiveExample")
      .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://10.20.30.40:9083")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "s3://abc/test/main")
      .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
       .config("access-key","key")
       .config("secret-key","key")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
      println("Start of SQL Session--------------------")
      spark.sql("show databases").show()
    spark.sql("select *from ace.visit limit 5").show()

  }

}
```

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).

Comment: The exception itself tells you that it is an authentication problem. Isn't it?

Comment: Hello vinod already try the same username and password  is correct.

Comment: Try the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811523/hw-to-load-files-in-sparksql-through-remote-hive-storage-s3-orc-using-spark-s/49812633#49812633

Comment: Try Still same error............. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).

Comment: Related post, may be helpful https://medium.com/@mrpowers/working-with-s3-and-spark-locally-1374bb0a354