# How to load files in sparksql through remote hive storage ( s3 orc) using spark/scala + code + configuration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hive, thrift

intellij(spark)--->Hive(Remote)---storage on S3(orc format)
Not able to read remote Hive table through spark/scala.

was able to read table schema but not able to read table.

> Error -Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the
>   username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the
>   fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties
>   (respectively).

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

object mainclas {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

     val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("hivetable")
      .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://10.20.30.40:9083")
       .config("access-key","PQHFFDEGGDDVDVV")
       .config("secret-key","FFGSGHhjhhhdjhJHJHHJGJHGjHH")
       .config("format", "orc")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

   val res = spark.sqlContext.sql("show tables").show()
   val res1 =spark.sql("select *from ace.visit limit 5").show() 
}
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("hivetable")
  .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://10.20.30.40:9083")
  .config("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId","PQHFFDEGGDDVDVV")
  .config("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","FFGSGHhjhhhdjhJHJHHJGJHGjHH")
  .config("format", "orc")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).

Comment: I've provided `s3n` which is for native s3 filesystem.. there are other versions `s3a` and pure `s3` which is block filesystem. Not sure whether that could be the reason but worth trying it, I suppose.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman, i am trying to connect to remote machine(not s3) so i removed both accesskey properties but getting Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime. error

Comment: Rahul: don't ever put AWS keys, private or (here) public into: stack overflow, source code, etc. That's how you get large bills.

Comment: Steve this is only sample keys not real one.

Answer (score 0):

you need to prefix all the `fs.` options with `spark.hadoop` if you are setting them in the spark config. And as noted: use s3a over s3n if you can.